# Sqlite: using alias for view in the SELECT query

Tags: sqlite

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE "table1"( "fld1" Text,  "fld2" Text );
```

The view:

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT * FROM table1
```

The query:

```
SELECT V.fld1 FROM v1 V
```

The result (column name): **V.fld1**

The question: 
Why the name of the field in the query result contains the alias of the view? What should be the text of the query to get valid field name?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AS`:

```
SELECT v1.fld1 AS fld1 from v1;
```

Comment: Yes, in this way the field name did not contain the the alias of the view. But the question remains open - why the name of alias included in the field name. With table there is no problems with such query.